# Scroll to bottom doesn't work but scroll to right above the row (scrollHeight is not updated correctly)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, typescript

What I want: The scroll bar to automatically scroll to the bottom whenever a new pin name row is added through `ng-keypress` hitting "enter".

Problem: The bar can automatically scroll but will only scroll to right above the row, which means I still have to manually scroll down to see the new added row

What I think: So the `scrollTop = scrollHeight - clientHeight;` makes sense to me. I have seen some answers regarding this using `scrollTop = scrollHeight;` instead, but I kept what I have here because after I manually scrolled to the bottom, where the scroll bar is at the position where I want it to be, I console logged the `scrollTop`, `scrollHeight`, and `clientHeight`, and they followed the equation. But when I console logged those attributes at where I put `scrollTop = scrollHeight - clientHeight;`, the `scrollHeight` will be 35 pixels less. Is this caused by some `offsetHeight` or wrong place to update `scrollTop`?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="add-new-pin-name-text" placeholder="Add Terminal(Pin) Name" data-lift="LocAttr?locId=sc_addPinsName&attr=placeholder" ng-model="newPinName" ng-keypress="newPinNameKeyPress($event)" id="add-pin" maxlength="40">
```

TypeScript

```
$scope.newPinNameKeyPress = function(e) {
    var pinNameListContainer = document.getElementById("listings-pins-container");
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $scope.addNewPin();
        if (pinNameListContainer){
            pinNameListContainer.scrollTop = pinNameListContainer.scrollHeight - pinNameListContainer.clientHeight;
        }
    }
};

$scope.addNewPin = function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("add-new-pin-name-text");
  if(($scope.newPinName === "") || /\s/g.test($scope.newPinName)) {
      if(element){
        element.blur();
      }
      return $rootScope.$emit('GenericError', i18n.symc_empty_pin_name);

  } else {
      $rootScope.$emit('AddNewPin', [{pinName:$scope.newPinName, pinNumber:""}]); // if this part's logic is needed, please let me know
      // I've tried to put "pinNameListContainer.scrollTop = pinNameListContainer.scrollHeight - pinNameListContainer.clientHeight;" here as well and it did the same thing
      return $scope.newPinName = "";
  }
};
```